# Explicit assignment of null

Tags: c#

```
string s1;
string s2 = null;

if (s1 == null) // compile error
if (s2 == null) // ok
```

I don't really understand why the explicit assignment is needed. Whats the difference between a null variable and an unassigned variable? I always assumed that unassigned variables were simply assigned as null by the runtime/compiler anyway. If they're not null, then what are they?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Unassigned *members* are automatically initialized to their default values (which is the null reference in the case for `string`).

Unassigned *local variables* are not assigned any value and trying to access a possibly unassigned variable will give a compile error.

Comment: its worth noting that its relatively easy for the compiler to determine that a local variable has not been assigned, whereas a member or global variable is very difficult. Hence, the difference in behaviour.

Comment: nothing is assigned TO null. Something can be assigned null :)

Comment: @martineau: There are no global variables in C#

Comment: @Winston: Not merely very difficult, generally impossible. :) (cf. halting problem)

Comment: By the way, the REASON this happens is because the compiler is being helpful.  This error message allows the compiler to help you find a huge class of errors you might miss otherwise.  The uptake--Don't EVER initialize your variables to null on the first pass.  Write the code without it and see if you REALLY need it, if you can't easily rewrite your code to not need the assignment then go ahead and add it, but never get in the habit of doing it automatically.

Comment: @Mark: Does java have similar behavior?

Comment: @Joren, the halting problem also applies to functions. Thus it is possible to write function which the compiler cannot determine whether or not you assign a local variable. It just that is much less likely and much easier to analyze then a whole program.

Comment: @Winston: Indeed the halting problem does apply to the local variable case. I didn't mean to imply that it doesn't. Of course, in either case what the compiler would do is to attempt to prove that a variable is assigned, and if it can't prove it, to consider it unassigned and give an error. For local variables, this approach is reasonable. For fields, you are correct in saying that getting a reasonable amount of accuracy is a lot harder. (But of course in both cases it's impossible to always know.) I was just being whimsical anyway :)

Answer (score 13):

The reason why explicit assignment is required is quite simple. This often a source of errors when people try to use unassigned/uninitialized variables.

By forcing the developer to do this, it eliminates errors which happen when the developer forgets to initialize the variable. And by initializing it, you're in control of it.

It's a good thing really! I dunno how often I had uninitialized or undefined variables in some of the scripting languages which took quite some time to be found ^^

Comment: In Python, you're forced to assign an initial value. You can't just say `a`, you have to say `a = None` or something. In JS you can do `var x;` but that means `var x = undefined;`, which is still assigning it a value. I don't see how this Java distinction helps. If you want to prevent uninitialized variables, don't have `null` in the language (like Haskell).

Comment: @Claudiu that is a bad thing, not good.  Gets you in the habit of initializing which stops path-finding error checking--for example with Java/C# int x;if(condA)x=5;else if(condB)x=7; print "x="+x; will give you an error because it realizes there is a case you didn't initialize x before using it (even though in two cases you DID initialize it.  If you always initialize variables then the system just can't do this type of check for you.

Answer (score 7):

1. If you have an unassigned local value, you are quite likely doing something stupid. Worse of all you are doing the sort of stupid thing that smart people can do in the heat of the moment, (everyone does something stupid every day).
2. Unlike some things that result in warnings, there's no possible advantage of using an unassigned value in a particular remarkable case.
3. The only cost difference between allowing an unassigned local or assuming a particular value, is a few keystrokes (normally `= null;` at most it could be `= default(SomeType);`

Banning such constructs is heavy on pros and low on cons. There's no technical reason why the language couldn't have been designed to allow unassigned locals, but the benefits of banning outweigh the disadvantages.

Answer (score 4):

The C# compiler does not allow the use of uninitialized local variables. An initially unassigned variable has no initial value.

Comment: so whats the difference between "no value" and null?

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet: `No value` is when the variable is `declared` but not `defined`. Something that doesn't really exist can't have a value. When you define variable it can have a value of null either by default or by assignment.

Comment: @Mike: it does exist. space is set aside for that variable somewhere. C# had a choice: assign that space `null` by default and get on with it, or force you to put `null` there yourself. i don't see much of a benefit doing it the latter way.

Comment: C# does not allow use of unassigned *local* variables. Fields, array elements, formal parameters, pointer dereferences, and so on, are considered to be "assigned at birth" as it were.

Comment: @Eric, thank you, I added the adjective _local_ to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the spec: [5.3 Definite assignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691172%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

> Definite assignment is a requirement in the following contexts:
>   A variable must be definitely assigned at each location where its value is obtained.

s1 and s2 are initially unassigned ([5.3.1 Initially assigned variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691173%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)), but only s2 *is considered definitely assigned at a given location,* [because] *all possible execution paths leading to that location contain at least one of the following:*

- *A simple assignment (Section 7.13.1) in which the variable is the left operand.*

As you can see, *null* is irrelevant in this context. Important is the assignment itself, but not the value.

Answer (score 2):

A variable that is never assigned a value holds an **undefined** value. In worst case, which actually occurs in most languages, this means, it can have **any** value, because it addresses some bit of memory, that is very likely to have been previously used for another purpose, potentially even by another programm. Some languages ensure that all variables are initialized to some sensible defaul values. However this may simply be a waste, since in the end it is a write operation, that may not be neccessary, doing this by default, it is a waste of time.

Comment: i suspect that C# will put some value in there anyway.. I know C didn't, but not sure about C#

Answer (score 0):

One thing to keep in mind is that scope will play a part in this. If you had defined S1 as a class variable then tested it inside a function the compiler would not have stopped and the code would run fine. The reason is that the variable is initialized when the class is instantiated.

Move inside a method and there is a good chance that you forgot something when testing the variable before initializing it.

The other caveat that I see is what does a string default to? (And more important is this in a specification that won't change? Keep in mind an empty string is not the same as a null assigned string. There is a way around this though as you can instead test with string.IsNullOrEmpty(S1) instead.